# Error ploting sequences in TraMineR R

Tags: r, plot, traminer

Just starting to experiment TraMiner, after having read the (very good) [User Guide](http://mephisto.unige.ch/pub/TraMineR/doc/TraMineR-Users-Guide.pdf)

I managed to create the sequences from my data, but as I'm trying to plot I got the following errors:

```
> seqiplot(my.data$sequences, title="My first sequences", withlegend = TRUE)
Error in do.call(plot, args = plist) : 
'what' must be a string or a function
```

Where does this come from and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you get an error because you override the `plot` function. This reproduce the error:

```
plot <- 1
do.call(plot,list(0))
Error in do.call(plot, list(0)) : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function
```

This should ork:

```
 rm(plot)
 seqiplot(my.data$sequences, title="My first sequences", withlegend = TRUE)
```

Comment: deleting plot object make it work, 

However since I'm not redefining myself plot, just loading libraries, might it be some conflict between Traminer and another Rpackage?

Comment: @AdrieanKhisbe Does the error occur when you run your script in a fresh R session? Did it occur again after you removed the plot object?

Comment: I does not occur after i remove plot. And yes I run the script either with Rscript, either with R --vanilla (sourcing it)

Comment: Then it seems clear that you once inadvertendly created a plot object before calling `seqiplot`

Comment: Since the answer solved your problem, why didn't you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error shows up because you restricted your sequence state object to the single variable `my.data$sequences`. Have you tried `my.data` instead?

Comment: my.data$sequences is the dataframe that hold my sequences objects, it's the one I need to give to function.
(otherwise: `Erreur : data is not a sequence object, use seqdef function to create one`